# Error 500 while trying to access rest API on server (was working on localhost during dev time)

Tags: rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I've created a Rest API to make my website communicate with a mysql database. Locally when developing it, I could run the application on eclipse using tomcat server then access my api from javascript using a path like this :

```
localhost:8080/backend/api/paintings
```

This path providing all the paintings from the database.

I've now rented a VPS and install everything (I think) on it to make it work, but when trying to access the same path I get en error 500 even though nothing changed and tomcat is running (I can access mydomain.com:8080 and it shows apache tomcat page).

My Rest API was built using Java EE.

The message I get as en error is

```
message "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet [mpart] a généré une exception

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet [mpart] a généré une exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

cause mère
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Map javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()'
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:528)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I've tried to access the api from my js code through both

```
mydomain.com:8080/backend/api/paintings 
localhost:8080/backend/api/paintings
```

and both gives an error.

I can provide any kind of code that could help solve this issue.

here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>mpart</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mpart</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>fr.demarquez.mpart.controllers</param-value>
        </init-param>
       <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>
                fr.demarquez.mpart.configs.CORSFilter;
                fr.demarquez.mpart.configs.LocalDateTimeAdapter;
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mpart</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping *mpart* servlet to */api/** but accessing it with */bacend/api** end point. Can you try this?

'''
        /backend/api/*
'''

Comment: This path is not an issue since it works like this when i run the java api on Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by going through the dependencies and solving problems with diferent versions of the jersey components.